# How to implement the like and share feature for a social networking website?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database, t-sql

I want to understand how the like button is actually implemented in a Web App (the database table part).

How to create a table structure for a like and share button?

Post can have share count and like count.

What about who shared and who liked entries?

Is this possible with a relational database or do I need another database type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically create two bridge tables to represent the like and share relationships between users and posts.

Sample ddl:

```
create table posts (
    post_id int primary key,
    -- more columns here: post date, title, content...
);

create table users (
    user_id int primary key,
    -- more columns here: user name, ...
);

create table user_likes_post (
    post_id int,
    user_id int,
    -- more columns here: date when the user liked the post, ...
    primary key(post_id, user_id)
);

create table user_shares_post (
    post_id int,
    user_id int,
    -- more columns here: date when the user shared the post, ...
    primary key(post_id, user_id)
);
```

Every time a users likes a post, a new record is created in the `user_likes_post` table; sames goes when a user shares a post with table `user_shares_post`.

Now, say that you want to know how many users liked each post, you can do:

```
select
    p.*,
    (select count(*) from user_likes_post ulp where ulp.post_id = p.post_id) no_likes   
from posts p
```

Comment: There are cases that using a single table instead of the two user_shares_post and user_likes_post, will provide better architecture. In this case you add another column for the type of the relation. There are pro and cons... Only small example: pro is that it is more flexible to add other types of relations in the future and less JOIN operations in some cases. sample for cons in single table is that we store more data (since we have the third column).

Comment: Can you give me a structure of what your talking about

Comment: @GMB...Brilliant work buddy...I have added the functionality to my application.
I couldnt think it would be that easy. Thanks!

Comment: @GMB....How about the Unlike Button